# what is the proper method of using resource files in MFC project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, advanced-installer

i have made a MFC-based game and my project includes images and sounds. Now i want to create an installer setup in order to distribute it.

i have used the resources by providing their exact path in e.g

```
img->Load(L"C:\\Users\\Ad33l's\\Desktop\\block mania\\block mania\\res\\db.png");

MCIWndCreate(NULL, NULL,WS_POPUP|MCIWNDF_NOPLAYBAR|MCIWNDF_NOMENU,L"C:\\Users\\Ad33l's\\Desktop\\block mania\\block mania\\res\\tick.wav");
```

1.Can someone tell me any way to avoid Hard-coding the actual resource path as these resource files will not be present at this same exact path in other computers ?

2.Also guide me to handle these resource files during the creation of standalone SETUP (i am using advance installer )

Comment: Do not use absolute path, always use relative path; relative to your EXE file is one solution.

Comment: yeah i was thinking so , but how to do it ? these functions require file path as argument ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(as an actual answer).

Do not use absolute path, always use relative path; relative to your EXE file is one solution.

The EXE path can be found using GetModuleFileName.

```
char appPath[MAXFILENAMELEN];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, appPath, MAXFILENAMELEN);
```

(addendum) appPath name is misleading, it contains the full name of the application; you need to extract the path from the full application name.

We do something like this:

(edit to make it compilable in unicode)

```
TCHAR applicationPath[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileName(NULL, applicationPath, MAX_PATH);
CString sSoundFile(applicationPath);
PathRemoveFileSpec(sSoundFile.GetBuffer());
sSoundFile.ReleaseBuffer();
```

From there, you can do something like (pseudocode-ish):

```
img.Load( appPath + "//Images//db.png" );
```

Comment: what is the purpose of appPath ? to store the path or the filename ? p.s  the path is stored in a variable type "wchar_t" , and these function accept this as arguments , not char const.

Comment: We still work in MBCS; not yet unicode, so char is ok for us.

Comment: GetModuleFileName() showing error ," argument type of char* is incompatible with parameter type LPWSTR "

Comment: thanks alot bro , i did it ^_^ , now i have to do research to understand TCHAR , WCHAR, LPWSTR things .... ' that nasty thing to strip the path is intelligent ! thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable that saves the directory they want to install your program in. After they choose the directory they want to install it in, go off of that. Or you can also use system folders like the appdata folder

Comment: can you elaborate how to do this all ?

Comment: CString appdata = getenv(_T("APPDATA")); // Gets the appdata folder  
  
CString appDataDir = appdata + _T("\\MyProgram\\"); // Sets appDataDir to appdata\MyProgram  
  
And you should let the user decide where to install your program. If you want the resources saved relative to that, let them pick a directory and save that directory as a variable

Answer (score 0):

A first solution would be to configure your setup project to install the installation files under the [DesktopFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368276(v=vs.85).aspx)\block mania\block mania\res. Then, you can access within your application the current user [Desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) location and append to it the remaining fix location (block mania\block mania\res).

Another solution would be to configure the setup project to create registries at install time which will store the paths of the installation files. Then, your application could read the installation paths from registry.

Finally you could also create at install time environment variables containing the paths of the installation file and, then use within your application the environment variables to access the installed files locations.